# How can I make apache to start up automatically on linux mint?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed Linux Mint 18.1 Serena and I have XAMPP 5.6.28-1 on my computer. After I turn on my computer, I must run the XAMPP control panel and I must start Apache and MySQL manually.

Does anyone know how this can be done automatically? I don't want to turn on Apache and MySql every time when I start / restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XAMPP you should use apache2, mysql-server, mysql-client, php5, phpmyadmin applications from repository of your distro. They will start automatically
.
`sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo service apache2 restart`
or just reboot your PC
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Comment: above commands will install php 7 which I didn't wanted. I am web developer and I need specific php and mysql version installed. That's why I install xampp 5.6.28-1 And neither apache or mysql starts automatically. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure? Version of PHP is indicated in packages name, you couldn't get php7 if you are installing php5.

Comment: Well: Line 1: sudo apt-get install apache2 Answer: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate

Comment: Line 2:    sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 Answer: libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: As you can see, I was unable to install older version of php, so I install XAMPP

Comment: I don't know, I have installed apache2 on latest 18.1 Mint without any problem. Still, you are right about php7 on latest OS (could you think about migrating to the older LTS system?), so, there are already (but on Ubuntu) a workaround http://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/762161#762161 . It's not easy though

Answer (score -1):

For Auto-start on boot/reboot, the following process will worked for me in Ubuntu 13.04 and XAMPP 1.8.1.

1. Create a script in init.d called lampp

`sudo gedit /etc/init.d/lampp`

2. Paste this code on the script and save

`#!/bin/bash
/opt/lampp/lampp start`

3. Give -x permissions to the file

`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/lampp`

4. Use update-rc.d to install init scripts to all runlevel by typing

`sudo update-rc.d lampp defaults`